# FragmentStatepageAdapter update current previous and next fragment when notifyDataSetChanged is called

Tags: android

I am working with ViewPager and FragmentStatePagerAdapter.
I have the following structure in my app :

- At index 0 Fragment A
- At index 1 to 7 Fragment B :
- each fragment B has 4 buttons :
- button C(load fragment c)
- D(load fragment d)
- E(load fragment e)
- F(load fragment f)

When ViewPager get set Fragment C is loaded by default.
What I am trying to achieve is the following :
-clicking on Button D should replace the current fragment with the Fragment associated with the button. this is done
The problem is that when the button is pressed the current fragment is replaced and the previous and the next too. How can I avoid this to happen?

This is my FragmentStatePageAdapter

```
 public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private final FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    private Fragment mFragmentAtPos0;
    public FirstPageListener listener = new FirstPageListener();
    private final class FirstPageListener implements
            ChannelPageFragmentListener {
        public void onSwitchToNextFragment() {
            mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(mFragmentAtPos0)
                    .commit();
            if (mFragmentAtPos0 instanceof LatestPostFragment) {
                mFragmentAtPos0 = new LiveLoungeFragment(listener);
            } else { // Instance of NextFragment
                mFragmentAtPos0 = new LatestPostFragment(listener);
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public void searchFields() {
            if (mFragmentAtPos0 instanceof LatestPostFragment) {
                ((LatestPostFragment) mFragmentAtPos0).reloadData("", false);
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        mFragmentManager = fm;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        String tag = null;
        if(position == 0)
        {
            Log.i("Latest Posts","getItem pos : 0");
            tag = DASHBOARD_FRAGMENT;
            fragment = new DashboardFragment();
        }
        else
        {
            Log.i("Latest Posts","getItem pos : " + position);

            if(label.equalsIgnoreCase("latest"))
            {
                fragment = new LatestPostFragment(listener);
                mFragmentAtPos0 = fragment;
                Log.i("Latest Posts","getItem latest");
            }
        else if(label.equalsIgnoreCase("events"))
            {
                fragment = new LiveLoungeFragment(listener);
                mFragmentAtPos0 = fragment;
                Log.i("Latest Posts","getItem events");
                label = "latest";
            }
               fragment = mFragmentAtPos0;
            showDrawerIcon();
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object)
    {
        Log.i("Latest Posts","getItemPosition : " + object.toString());
        if (object instanceof LatestPostFragment) {
            Log.i("Latest Posts","getItemPosition latestpost");

            return POSITION_NONE;
        }
        if (object instanceof LiveLoungeFragment) {
            Log.i("Latest Posts","getItemPosition livelounge");

            return POSITION_NONE;
        }
        return POSITION_UNCHANGED;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return channels.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Log.i(TAG,"title : " + position);

        return channels.get(position).getSport().name();
    }
}`
```

This is the trigger for the buttons :

```
((Button) findViewById(R.id.latest)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                label = "latest";
                sub_pressed = true;
                sub_position = "current";
                currentPosition = mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
                getCategoryFromName((String) mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(currentPosition).toString());
                LatestPostFragment.firstPageListener.onSwitchToNextFragment();
            }
        });((Button) findViewById(R.id.events)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                label = "events";
                sub_pressed = true;
                sub_position = "current";
                currentPosition = mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
                getCategoryFromName((String) mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(currentPosition).toString());
                LatestPostFragment.firstPageListener.onSwitchToNextFragment();
            }
        });
```

Basically when the button get pressed the listener for onSwitchToNextFragment get called and notifyDataSetChanged is called.

This is the log coming from getItemPosition

> 04-28 10:24:46.940    5127-5127/com.breathesport.breathesportapp I/Latest Posts﹕ getItemPosition : LatestPostFragment{395c1afe #0 id=0x7f0a008a}
>   04-28 10:24:46.940    5127-5127/com.breathesport.breathesportapp I/Latest Posts﹕ getItemPosition latestpost
>   04-28 10:24:46.940    5127-5127/com.breathesport.breathesportapp I/Latest Posts﹕ getItemPosition : LatestPostFragment{1ae5125f #2 id=0x7f0a008a}
>   04-28 10:24:46.940    5127-5127/com.breathesport.breathesportapp I/Latest Posts﹕ getItemPosition latestpost
>   04-28 10:24:46.940    5127-5127/com.breathesport.breathesportapp I/Latest Posts﹕ getItemPosition : LatestPostFragment{139bf4ac #1 id=0x7f0a008a}
>   04-28 10:24:46.940    5127-5127/com.breathesport.breathesportapp I/Latest Posts﹕ getItemPosition latestpost
>   04-28 10:24:46.946    5127-5127/com.breathesport.breathesportapp I/Latest Posts﹕ getItem pos : 3
>   04-28 10:24:46.946    5127-5127/com.breathesport.breathesportapp I/Latest Posts﹕ getItem latest
>   04-28 10:24:46.946    5127-5127/com.breathesport.breathesportapp I/Latest Posts﹕ getItem pos : 2
>   04-28 10:24:46.946    5127-5127/com.breathesport.breathesportapp I/Latest Posts﹕ getItem latest
>   04-28 10:24:46.946    5127-5127/com.breathesport.breathesportapp I/Latest Posts﹕ getItem pos : 4
>   04-28 10:24:46.946    5127-5127/com.breathesport.breathesportapp I/Latest Posts﹕ getItem latest

My guess is that getItemPosition cannot understand which one is the currentFragment, I've probably done something wrong in my implementation.
I hope somebody could help